# Lazy computation of primes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes

I wanted to give Haskell a try, and I started with a simple exercise I found [here](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs173/2008/Assignments/04-laziness-prog.html).

> 1. Write `isPrime :: Integer -> Bool`, which determines whether a given
>      integer is prime.
> 2. Define `primes :: [Integer]`, the list of all primes.
> 3. Revise `isPrime` so that it only tests divisibility by prime factors.

#### My answer to Q1

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime v = let maxDiv = floor(sqrt (fromIntegral v))
            in all (\x -> (v `rem` x) /= 0) [2..maxDiv]
```

This one was easy, except for the explicit numeric types conversions I had a hard time to get right.

#### My answer to Q2

```
primes = filter isPrime [0..]
```

This one was easy, too.

#### My answer to Q3

It took me several hours to answer this one. I quickly understood that `isPrime` could leverage the values already computed in the array `primes`. So, my first attempt was :

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime v | v < 2 = False
          | otherwise = all (\x -> (v `rem` x) /= 0) (takeWhile (<v) primes)
```

`isPrime` works fine for v=0 and v=1, but hangs forever for v>1. Ok, I get it : the mutual recursion creates an infinite loop, due to `takeWhile` trying to access a `primes` element which is not yet computed.

One thing I don't understand though, is why `primes !! 0` and `primes !! 1` hang forever, too.

I tried many approaches for replacing this `(takeWhile (<v) primes)` by an expression that would stop before reaching a not-yet-computed value. I came to this solution :

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime v | v < 2 = False
          | v == 2 = True
          | otherwise = all (\x -> (v `rem` x) /= 0) (takeWhile' (\t -> t*t<=v) primes)

takeWhile' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile' p (x:xs) = if p x then x : takeWhile' p xs else [x]
```

This solution works. But I had to define a `takeWhile'` that works just like `takeWhile`, but also includes the first non-matching element.

Here are my questions to you :

**QA** : why do `primes !! 0` and `primes !! 1` hangs in my first attempt ?

**QB** : is there a magical `takeWhileOnlyForAlreadyComputedElements` function ? Or a construct that would prevent the infinite loop of this mutual recursion ?

**QC** : does `takeWhile'` already exist in the stdlib ? Or maybe the same effect can be achieved in a simpler way ?

Comment: I realize QA may be a better fit on stackoverflow, but the questions I'm more interrested in are QB and QC, which (I think) belong to codereview.

Comment: QC: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=takeWhile Hoogle is very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer to your questions, but a correction for your first, looping attempt for Q3:

Things get much easier if you initially have at least one prime number in your list. You *could* ensure this by a separate case in `isPrime`, but why not cheat a little bit, and add it directly?

```
primes = 2 : filter isPrime [3..]
```

Then you can use your solution for Q1 without much changes (I took the freedom to kill some parens etc):

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime v = let maxDiv = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral v
            in all ((/= 0).(v `rem`)) $ takeWhile (<= maxDiv) primes
```

However, this is not the best way to generate a list of primes. Read the excellent paper http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf for details.

**[Edit]**

I forgot to mention http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers with many interesting techniques.

Comment: Thanks, initializing `primes` with the first value is clearly the way to go. I'll remember the `$` function, too (I saw it in the Prelude, but didn't get its usefulness).